# Why is the function $a^z$ multi-valued?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For $a \in \mathbb C$, $z \in \mathbb C \mapsto f(z) = a^z$ is multi-valued. Why so? Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: when you put a complex number in polar form, in how many ways can you state its argument?

Comment: Isn't $a^z = \exp z \log a$? Is this because $\log a$ can have many values?

Comment: Who told you that it is multi-valued? If you fix a value for $\log(a)$ it is single-valued, in contrast to $z^a$ which **is** multi-valued for general complex $a$.

Comment: This phenomenon also arises in the reals: $1^{1/2}$ can be defined to be $-1$ as well as $1$. The complex numbers just make it in a more... complex way.

Comment: I think it depends on how you define it. You could define $e^z$ (and, in general, $a^z$) as multi-valued functions in contrast to $\exp(z)$, which is single-valued. On the other hand, you could just use the principle branch of the logarithm and define $a^z = \exp(z\log(a))$. Then it's single-valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the natural logarithm may be considered a multi-valued function and $a^z$ is defined as $\exp\{z\log a\}$. Euler's formula allows us to observe that, for any complex number
$$
a=r(\cos \varphi + i\sin \varphi ),
$$
where $r$ is a non-negative real number, one possible value for $a$'s natural logarithm is
$$
\log a= \log r + \varphi i.
$$
Because $\cos$ and $\sin$ are periodic functions, the natural logarithm may be considered a multi-valued function, with
$$
\log a=\{ \log r + (\varphi + 2\pi k)i:k \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Natural_logarithm)).

Comment: You silently switch from $\log a$ to $\log z$. IMO it is **not** multivalued as a function of $z$.

Comment: @gammatester Thank you for the comment. It was a typo. As Friedrich Philipp wrote in the comments, it depends on how you define it. But it might be considered a multi-valued function.